# bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

Recently I've started with [ruby on rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and stuck with `bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text` which should create `model` with two `columns`, unfortunately the output is like:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/sbin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:284:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Unknown alias: default1 (Psych::BadAlias)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:284:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:284:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:302:in `block in revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each_slice'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:302:in `block in revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each_slice'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:276:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:37:in `to_ruby'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:246:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:99:in `database_configuration'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:314:in `active_record_configured?'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:248:in `disconnect_database'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:97:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

There were some rvm privileages issue, which has been resolved with:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/
```

and before `generate model` there were called `sudo chmod o-w /usr/local/`. Suppose none of them affect above issue.

Appreciate any solutions.

**EDIT:**
I looked for `database_configuration` with no luck.. I thought this basic `database.yml` file has nothing in common as it contains:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default1
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: it says it can't load database configuration, did you create the `database.yml` file ? if yes could you paste it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

database configuration is missing for that particular environment.

If database details are given.Please make sure there are no white space in database.yml.Indentation should be maintanied. Single extra space can cause problem in configuration.

Comment: And one more thing you can check is connect to development database  from command line.